# Extracting part of a domain name

Tags: php, variables, get

I have a url, `members.exampledomain.com`, and I would like to display only `exampledomain` onto my page.

For example `http://members.exampledomain.com`'s index page has something like

```
    <img src="members/images/logoexampledomain.png" />
```

Comment: I updated your example to reflect what I think you're actually asking for.  Feel free to correct it if my assessment was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

and see if there is something you like there :)

Else if it is allways the same url like that, you can use `$pieces = explode('.', $url);` and `$pieces[1]` will contain exampledomain

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work for you I have used javascript before to retrieve information out of urls before on pages where php would not run.  I believe I retrieved it using window.location and had a function figure out what characters to look at so it would know where to split the url or retrieve out the information you want.

Comment: Actually that might work best, cause on my clients server for some reason some of my php doesnt work. Can u give me an example. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide something a little more substantial than, "Use Javascript"?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this with the domain as suggested above, the following code should work for you.

```
 $full_domain = 'members.example.com';
 $parts = explode('.', $full_domain);
 array_slice($parts, -2, 2);
 $domain = implode('.', $parts);
 echo $domain;
```

This is a basic string parser for the domain.  Things get much more complex when you are using multiple domains on the same script (aka Virtual hosting), and those domains have varying extensions such as .com.au .

If you wish to get the 'member' portion of the domain, you can add the following code after the above code:

```
 $member = rtrim(str_replace($domain, '', $full_domain), '.');
 echo $member;
```